# Behaviour of std::array<bool> vs. std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Does the `std::array<bool>` implement the same bit packing memory optimisation that `std::vector<bool>` does?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Even the standard commitee [learnt about their mistakes](https://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html) ;-)

Comment: @NeilButterworth why? Why is this not a valid representation of `array<bool, 2>`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a2087c3125e0f52

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb because [*This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Bit fields don't have the same semantics as `bool[]`.

Comment: @zett42 I don't understand `array<bool, 2>` is not a bitfield. That it contains bitfields in its implementation details should be irrelevent, I think. Can you please explain? What *are* the semantics of a "struct holding a C-style array"? Do you say that `struct C { bool a[2]; };` is a valid implementation of `array<bool, 2>`? Clearly the text is about the interface of `array<bool, 2>`, for which it is irrelevant what it internally contains (really the text should be more clear IMO)

Comment: @Johannes But what about taking the address of elements of `array<bool>` if those elements were bitfields?

Comment: @NeilButterworth that's a better explanation, afaics.

Comment: @Johannes that's part of the semantics that you can take the address.

Comment: You can use std::bitset with the same purpose of std::array<bool>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, `std::array` has no specialization for *bool* type.

You can find more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), but, basically, `std::array` is just a:

> an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N]

and in case of *bool* you might consider it as a C-style array of bools, not any kind of bitset.